# After installing flutter 3.19.1, this is the error i got

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

```
[first_app] flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
  flutter_lints 2.0.3 (3.0.1 available)
+ leak_tracker 10.0.0 (10.0.4 available)
+ leak_tracker_flutter_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.3 available)
+ leak_tracker_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.1 available)
  lints 2.1.1 (3.0.0 available)
> matcher 0.12.16+1 (was 0.12.16)
> material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (was 0.5.0)
> meta 1.11.0 (was 1.10.0) (1.12.0 available)
> path 1.9.0 (was 1.8.3)
  test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
+ vm_service 13.0.0 (14.0.0 available)
These packages are no longer being depended on:
- web 0.3.0
Changed 9 dependencies!
8 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
exit code 0
```

I installed the latest version of flutter, and I can't run a simple hello world application to display on flutter emultor on vscode. Instead I got the above error message!

Comment: The output you posted above is not an error. Can you post the actual error message when you run the app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.